# Return rows that of both table that has value in month column

Tags: sql

I have **2** tables and I want to **combine** them in a way that they give data that are base on month. like these :

***table1 :***

```
month   | data1 | data2
--------|-------|------
6       | 1     | 1     
5       | 1     | 1     
4       | 1     | 2     
2       | 1     | 2     
1       | 1     | 3
```

***table2 :***

```
month   | data3
--------|------
7       | 1
6       | 1
4       | 1
3       | 1
1       | 2
```

***=> tableResult :***

```
month   | data1 | data2 | data3
--------|-------|-------|-------
7       | 0     | 0     | 1
6       | 1     | 1     | 1
5       | 1     | 1     | 0
4       | 1     | 2     | 1
3       | 0     | 0     | 1
2       | 1     | 2     | 0
1       | 1     | 3     | 2
```

Is it possible to obtain that ***tableresult*** in `sql query` ? 
or the only option is to query each table then process it with php?
by the way **table1** and **table2** are both views if it matters

Comment: Do a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: more visible question make it much more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join and union

```
   select t1.month,data1,data1,t2.data3
   from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.month=t2.month
   union
   select t2.month,t1.data1,t1.date2,t2.data3
   from  table1 t1 right join table2 t2 on t1.month=t2.month
```

Comment: A lot of Thanks! I haven't encounter joins until now, I will be reading about it more later. By the way it works, I modify it a little bit so it displays 0 instead of null

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.month, t2.month) as month,
       coalesce(t1.data1, 0) as data1,
       coalesce(t1.data2, 0) as data2,
       coalesce(t2.data3, 0) as data3
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.month = t2.month;
```